# Error asking me to create an already existing 'activity_main.xml' file

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-activity

I recently started a project and created a Splash screen for it. After creating a new activity, the splash screen activity page is showing an error. It is asking me to create the 'activity_main.xml' file even though it exists. Here is the screenshot:

[Image showing error and xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YllRH.png)

Comment: You should use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @luca_999! It worked